# Classification of Band as a Collective Noun

Tags: collective-nouns

1. The band of musicians was playing.- *here band is a collective noun*.
2. The musical band is popular among teenagers.- *Can I say band is a collective noun in this context?*

Comment: Yes, _band_ is a venerial term for a group of people with some internal cohesion and a goal in common. It used to be more common than it is now -- _Band of Brothers_ is from 'Henry V' -- and less specialized. But in American English it's specialized for music when used for people (_rubber band, bandsaw, the 1500 Ǻngström band,_, etc. are a different _band_ of meanings. In the USA _join a band_ means to become a member of a musical ensemble; ditto _lead a band, have (a/one's own) band, battle of the bands,_ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In your second example, "of musicians" would be implicit. Similarly, in your first example, you could simply say that the band was playing and it would still be referring to the collective.